# Specific A* Pathfinding Issue with Implementation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path-finding, a-star

I'm having some issues with my A* Implementation. It occasionally decides to do strange things on my grid, like ignoring movement costs and moving thru a high cost area, or going a tile in the wrong direction before getting back on track.

I've officially spent far too many hours on it then I'd like to admit so I'm reaching out to find a pair of fresh eyes.

```
private List<Vector2> PathFromTo(Vector2 startID, Vector2 targetID){
    List<Vector2> path = new List<Vector2> ();
    List<Node> closedList = new List<Node> ();
    List<Node> openList = new List<Node> ();
    Node startNode = nodeList.Find (tgt => tgt.nodeID == new Vector2 (startID.x, startID.y));
    if (startNode == null)
        return path;
    Node targetNode = nodeList.Find (tgt => tgt.nodeID == new Vector2 (targetID.x, targetID.y));
    if (targetNode == null)
        return path;

    openList.Add (startNode);

    while (openList.Count > 0) {
        Node current = openList [0];
        for (int i = 1; i < openList.Count; i++) 
            if (openList [i].GetFCost () <= current.GetFCost () && openList [i].GetHCost () < current.GetHCost ()) 
                current = openList [i];

        openList.Remove (current);
        closedList.Add (current);

        if (current == targetNode) {
            RetracePath (startNode, targetNode, ref path);
            return path;
        }

        foreach(Vector2 neighbour in current.neighbors) {
            Node neighbourNode = nodeList.Find (tgt => tgt.nodeID == new Vector2 (neighbour.x, neighbour.y));
            CheckNeighbor(ref neighbourNode, ref current, ref targetNode, ref closedList, ref openList);
        }
    }
    return path;
}

private void CheckNeighbor(ref Node neighborTile, ref Node currentTile, ref Node targetTile, ref List<Node> closedList, ref List<Node> openList){
    if (neighborTile != null) {
        if (!neighborTile.passable || closedList.Contains (neighborTile)) {
        } else {
            int newCostToNeighbor = (int)(currentTile.moveCost + CalculateDistance (currentTile.position, neighborTile.position));
            if (newCostToNeighbor < neighborTile.GetGCost() || !openList.Contains (neighborTile)) {
                neighborTile.SetGCost (newCostToNeighbor);
                neighborTile.SetHCost (CalculateDistance (neighborTile.position, targetTile.position));
                neighborTile.SetParent (currentTile);

                if (!openList.Contains (neighborTile)) 
                    openList.Add (neighborTile);
            }
        }
    }
}

public float CalculateDistance(Vector2 tileA_pos, Vector2 tileB_pos){ 
    float dX = Mathf.Abs (tileB_pos.x - tileA_pos.x); 
    float dY = Mathf.Abs (tileB_pos.y - tileA_pos.y); 
    float shift1 = -(tileA_pos.x + tileA_pos.y); 
    float shift2 = -(tileB_pos.x + tileB_pos.y); 
    float dZ = Mathf.Abs (shift2 - shift1); 
    return Mathf.Max (dX, dY, dZ); 
}

private void RetracePath(Node start, Node end, ref List<Vector2> pathInfo){
    pathInfo = new List<Vector2> ();
    Node current = end;
    while (current != start) {
        pathInfo.Add (current.nodeID);
        current = current.GetParent ();
    }
    pathInfo.Reverse ();
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Were you able to reproduce your issues? If so, have you tried to debug your code to at least try to pinpoint where things go wrong?

Comment: I have tried messing with path costs and starting positions but the board I'm using uses some random generation so it can be a bit difficult to pin down an exact pattern. 

Where it breaks down worst is where tiles are passable but have a high move cost. Rather than going around the tile, it passes thru them. The tile costs are correct, it just generates an improper path, thus, I assume, the implementation is incorrect.

Comment: You can log/store the seeds of your random functions to make it easier to reproduce issues. You can initialize a random function with a seed to make it always produce the same results. Anyway, about your code: my feeling says your problems have something to do with the line `int newCostToNeighbor = ...` in `CheckNeighbor`, are you sure you need `currentTile.moveCost` there and not `neighborTile.moveCost`?

Comment: I made that change and it does not appear to have solved the issue. (Though funny enough I think it is probably correct to fix that).

Comment: You mention 'high cost tiles', this is not obviously present in your code sample. (How) Is this handled in `CalculateDistance `?

Comment: @NickB. You should edit your question to add your CalculateDistance method. It's too much code to fit nicely in a comment. Please also delete that comment afterwards. Oh and while you're editing your question, please also remove the [oop] tag from it as your problem is not about object-oriented programming (you don´t have any issues with inheritance or abstraction for example).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do in that CaluclateDistance() method but it's only looking at the x and y positions of the tiles, how/where is the cost implemented?

Comment: Deleted the Comment and tag, added the code as per PJvG's request. The board I'm using is a Hex Grid, and the implementation for Calc Distance was the recommended one I found online. I have never done a Hex Grid before now and it may be what's screwing me up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After far too many hours (And a full night's sleep) I was able to figure it out. The issue had to do with the CheckNeighbor Function. The new method looks like this:

```
private void CheckNeighbor(ref Node neighborTile, ref Node currentTile, ref Node targetTile, ref List<Node> closedList, ref List<Node> openList, bool ignoreMoveCost = false){
    if (neighborTile != null) {
        if (!neighborTile.passable || closedList.Contains (neighborTile)) {
        } else {
            int newCostToNeighbor = (int)((ignoreMoveCost ? 1 : neighborTile.moveCost) + currentTile.GetGCost() + CalculateDistance (currentTile.position, neighborTile.position));
            if (!openList.Contains (neighborTile)) {
                openList.Add (neighborTile);
            } else if (newCostToNeighbor >= neighborTile.GetGCost ()) {
                return;
            }
            neighborTile.SetParent (currentTile);
            neighborTile.SetGCost (newCostToNeighbor);
            neighborTile.SetHCost (CalculateDistance (currentTile.position, neighborTile.position));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the `CalculateDistance` method you show in the comments I wrote the following test program: (Assuming your `Mathf` is similar to `System.Math`)

```
for (int y = -4; y < 5; y++)
{
    for (int x = -4; x < 5; x++)
    {
        var dst = CalculateDistance(new Vector2(x, y), new Vector2());
        Console.Write($"{((int)dst):D1} ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The test program tests all coordinates between (-4,-4) and (4, 4) and calculates their distance to (0,0) The output:

```
8 7 6 5 4 4 4 4 4
7 6 5 4 3 3 3 3 4
6 5 4 3 2 2 2 3 4
5 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4
4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4
4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 5
4 3 2 2 2 3 4 5 6
4 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 7
4 4 4 4 4 5 6 7 8
```

As you can see the output is completely wacky, you would expect the bottom right corner to be just as far from (0,0) as the top right corner, but it isn't. Perhaps you need to rewrite your `CalculateDistance` method.

You seem to calculate a dX, dY and dZ, which is impossible given you have only 2 coordinates (`Vector2`).

---

Edit: You can simpy use pythagoras to figure out the distance between two points if no 'weights' are recorded:

```
var dist = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(point1.x - point2.x, 2) + Math.Pow(point1.y - point2.y, 2));
```

Comment: Good analysis and debugging, but *technically* this isn't an answer.  If you could suggest a way to fix it, you would get a better score.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Point taken. Added a simple solution. Do note OP asks for help with debugging, _what is wrong here?_, not necessarily for a complete solution. Maybe this style of question is less fitting on StackOverflow.

Comment: I changed to the new formula and it has not solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state whether or not you allow diagonal moves, but one of these two routines for CalculateDistance should suffice:

```
    public static readonly int D = 1;
    public static readonly int D2 = 1;

    public static float CalculateDistance(Vector2 tileA_pos, Vector2 tileB_pos)
    {
        float dX = Math.Abs(tileB_pos.x - tileA_pos.x);
        float dY = Math.Abs(tileB_pos.y - tileA_pos.y);
        return D * (dX + dY);
    }

    public static float CalculateDistanceDiagonalsAllowed(Vector2 tileA_pos, Vector2 tileB_pos)
    {
        float dX = Math.Abs(tileB_pos.x - tileA_pos.x);
        float dY = Math.Abs(tileB_pos.y - tileA_pos.y);
        return D * (dX + dY) + (D2 - 2 * D) * (dX < dY ? dX : dY);
    }
```

Where D is the cost of a vertical/horizontal move, and D2 is the cost of a diagonal move - you may wish to set this to 1 or Sqrt(2) as required. I am assuming that currentTile.moveCost is being used to define high/low cost tiles

Comment: I tried both of these solutions and it did not solve the issue.